# javascript two error of uncaught of syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write simple code in angularjs and i will facing these two erros that are the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

And my html file is this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Invoice1</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js" ></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="invoice1.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="invoice1" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
                <b>Invoice</b>

                <div>
    Quantity:<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qant" required >
                </div>
                <div>
    Cost:<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" required />
                        <select ng-model=invoice.incurr>
            <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
                        </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                <b>Total:</b>
                <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
                {{invoice.total(c)|currency:c}}
                </span>
                <button ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>

                </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the main error with this file due to which my app not work properly
and i will see the complete code and cant find error in the code
And script file is this

```
(function(angular)){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('invoice1',[])
    .controller('InvoiceController',function()){
            this.qant=1;
            this.cost=2;
            this.incurr='EUR';
            this.currencies=['USD','EUR','CNY'];
            this.usdToForeignRates={
                USD:1,
                EUR:0.79,
                CNY:6.09
            };
            this.total=function.total(outcurr){
                return this.convertCurrency(this.qant * this.cost, this.incurr,outcurr);
            };
            this.convertCurrency=function convertCurrency(amount,incurr,outcurr){
                return amount * this.usdToForeignRates[outcurr]/this.usdToForeignRates[incurr]
            };
            this.pay=function pay(){
                window.alert("Thanx! check your currency");
            };
    });

})(window.angular);

//window.alert("thanx!");
```

Comment: You really need to format your code dude, if you expect any help.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

```
this.pay=function pay(){
                window.alert("Thanx! check your currency");
            };
    }) //<----this here doesnt have a matching "(" ;

}) //----this here doesnt have a matching "(" (window.angular);
```

because you have closed off your functions where you shouldnt have here

```
(function(angular)) <----
```

and here

```
.controller('InvoiceController',function()) <----
```

[Jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a good resource to check your javascript

Answer (score -1):

Your code is full of errors. Here is without

- `(function(angular))`
- `.controller('InvoiceController',function()){`
- and do not use `function.total`

Use some IDE, or online tools like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

```
 (function(angular){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('invoice1',[])
    .controller('InvoiceController',function(){
            this.qant=1;
            this.cost=2;
            this.incurr='EUR';
            this.currencies=['USD','EUR','CNY'];
            this.usdToForeignRates={
                USD:1,
                EUR:0.79,
                CNY:6.09
            };
            this.total=function (outcurr){
                return this.convertCurrency(this.qant * this.cost, this.incurr,outcurr);
            };
            this.convertCurrency=function convertCurrency(amount,incurr,outcurr){
                return amount * this.usdToForeignRates[outcurr]/this.usdToForeignRates[incurr];
            };
            this.pay=function pay(){
                window.alert("Thanx! check your currency");
            };
    });

})(window.angular);
```